# set multiple Validator for single textbox

Tags: asp.net

i am new to asp.net and facing some small small problem in it and the problem is to set the multiple validator for a single `Textbox`. I set the validation but while running it, the validation takes step-by-step, not in a single place.

Here's my code:

```
<td align="right" style="padding-right: 5px; width: 50%;">
    <asp:Label ID="lblConformPassword" runat="server" Text="CONFORMPASSWORD &nbsp;:"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td align="left" style="padding-left: 5px; width: 50%; color: #FF0000;">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtConformPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="70%"
        ForeColor="red" AutoCompleteType="Office"></asp:TextBox>
    * &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtConformPassword"
        ErrorMessage="You can't leave this empty." Style="color: #FF0000;"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rfvConformPassword" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtConformPassword"
        ErrorMessage="SEE THE NOTE" ValidationExpression="(?=^.{6,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W+)(?![.\n]).*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToCompare="txtpassword"
        ControlToValidate="txtconformpassword" ErrorMessage="Password And ConformPassword Should Be Same."
        Display="Dynamic" Style="color: #FF0000; margin-left: 0px"></asp:CompareValidator>
    <br />
</td>
```

All of the validation should take place in single line. How can set I it?
Can any one help me on this process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok..I guess there is one property in all this validator Display="dynamic"
You can try that.and you can take div structure instead of 
.also you have to put display=dynamic in all validators
Thanks

Comment: i am sorry i can't able to understand it can you make it more clear..,

Comment: You have use  Display="Dynamic" only in CompareValidator..you will also have to put that in regular expression as well as in required field validators like this <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtConformPassword" display="dynamic"
        ErrorMessage="You can't leave this empty." Style="color: #FF0000;"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

Comment: you have used <br/> tag remove that between all validators and I am damm sure it will work dear..also instead of error message property you can "Text" property in all those validators

Comment: Welcome, you can up my comments to so that anyone comes searching over here can quickly identify the helpfull comment. Cheers Guy

Comment: plz see this link and help me to solve the problam http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827979/textbox-and-lable

Answer (score 1):

Use Display="dynamic" property of validators. hope this helps!!