# textbox and label position issue

Tags: asp.net, textbox, label

I am new to asp.net and facing some small problem in it. Problem is to set the `Textbox` and `label` are in different position and while I use the `<br/>` tag the form is looking very bad how can I resolve the flow?

**code is:**

```
<tr>
        <td align="right" style="padding-right: 5px;" class="style6">
            <asp:Label ID="lblEmailId" runat="server" Text="EMAIL ID &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td align="left" style="padding-left: 5px;" class="style6"> 
        <br/><br/><br/>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailId" runat="server" Width="70%" AutoCompleteType="Office"></asp:TextBox>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmailId"
                ErrorMessage="You can't leave this empty." Style="color: #FF0000;"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rfvEmailId" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmailId"
                ErrorMessage="Not a Valid Email Address" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
                ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" Style="color: #FF0000;" />&nbsp;<br />
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" style="padding-right: 5px; " class="style6">
            <asp:Label ID="lblPhoneNo" runat="server" Text="PHONE NO.&nbsp;&nbsp;:"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td align="left" style="padding-left: 5px; " class="style6">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhoneNo" runat="server" Width="70%" AutoCompleteType="Office"></asp:TextBox>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPhoneNo"
                ErrorMessage="You can't leave this empty." Style="color: #FF0000;"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rfvPhoneNo" ControlToValidate="txtPhoneNo" ValidationExpression="\d{10}"
                ErrorMessage="The number must be 10 numeric digits!" runat="server" Style="color: #FF0000;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

plz can any one help me on this flow...,

Comment: One sugesstion learn `HTML/Css` first, Inline css is BAD practise. refer http://www.w3schools.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. get rid of `<br />` and `&nbsp;` tags.
2. set the RequiredFieldValidator and RegularExpressionValidator to dynamically display

   ```
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmailId"
           ErrorMessage="You can't leave this empty." Style="color: #FF0000;" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rfvEmailId" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmailId"
           ErrorMessage="Not a Valid Email Address" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
           ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" Style="color: #FF0000;" Display="Dynamic"/>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Within the same `<tr>` element place the label in one `<td>` and the text box in the other e.g:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Name
        </td>
        <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Surname
        </td>
        <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurname" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Age
        </td>
        <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right;">
        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" /> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Produces the following layout:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<br/><br/><br/>`

And really, DON'T use designer for layout! Use it only for preview and adding new custom controls.

Comment: if i remove the <br/> tag the textbox is moving up it is not exatly facing the lable.

Comment: i am sorry i can't understand the thing you are telling....,

Comment: What do you mean by "different position"? How it should be located?

Comment: like this lable:textbox not like this lable down and textbox up